# is an i3 processor enough for windows and android development?

Tags: laptop

i want to buy a new laptop and my budget allows me to buy one with an i3 processor and 4gb of RAM. i will install win8 on it. what i'll be doing is mostly work with visual studio 2013, doing WPF desktop apps and maybe i'll get into Win8 apps and Windows mobile apps. i would also like to be able to do some android development (i know that the emulator has some requirements). Considering that, should I buy this configuration (is it enough for my needs) or wait and save up some more and buy a laptop with an i5 cpu?

Comment: A `Pentium D` from 2004 is enough for Android development.  I mean its not exactly the most CPU intensive task on a computer today.  Your unlikely to realistically notice the difference between an i5 and i3 device.  Yes;  There are advantages to 32GB, the best CPU on the market, and SSD's in a RAID 5 configuration but none of those are required for it.

Comment: 4 GB is pretty low. My dev machine has 32 GB, which admittedly is on the high side, but I'd pause before accepting 8 GB for a dev machine. OTOH, I've done software development using much less powerful machines in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Application Development using IDEs such as Visual Studio or Eclipse could benefit from a powerful processor such as an i5. Technically you can run Visual Studio on i3 just fine,but given the choice save up some more and buy a laptop with an i5 CPU, although I'd recommend an i7 but since that's out of budget ,go for an i5.